# Installing cairo on Ubuntu/Heroku - what's my Heroku superuser?

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, cairo

When I follow the instructions to install cairo, logged into my Heroku shell, with

```
~ $ su apt-get install libcairo2-dev
```

(http://www.cairographics.org/download/)

I get

password:

Does anyone know if a Heroku account gives you superuser access? No password I know of works.

Ultimately, I am trying to accomplish installing R with PNG support, which has a dependency on cairo for chart output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing something directly on a Dyno has no effect: the dyno's filesystem is reverted back to its "original" (post-compilation, what's know as "slug") every reboot, or every time a new dyno is spun up for your app.

To have Cairo, you need to add it as part of your slug's build process. You can either:

1) Read up on Vulcan (https://github.com/heroku/vulcan) and do it yourself, or:

2) Use a build pack that already has Cairo (buildpacks: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/third-party-buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack; one that has Cairo: https://github.com/rumblelabs/heroku-buildpack-cairo for example, or https://github.com/mojodna/heroku-buildpack-nodejs#cairo)

Comment: Wow you found a node.js build with cairo -sweet! Thank you.

Comment: It looks like Vulcan is deprecated!

Answer (score 0):

You are not root. You forgot "sudo". How is this related to Heroku?

Comment: Heroku's OS is a flavor of Ubuntu. The Heroku she'll doesn't recognize the sudo command.

Comment: Correction, it's su not sudo - but I have no idea what the password would be. It's not the password of my heroku account.

Comment: Hang on... you are try to install cairo *on heroku*? That wouldn't work anyways. You'd be installing it on one dyno, but once it's rebooted, or your app spins up on another dyno, the changes would be lost. You need it as part of your buildpack. Look up "Vulcan".